# How to read a file for mulipart file upload from separate features in another location?- Karate DSL

Tags: file-upload, multipartform-data, karate

**To be brief with the requirement:**

My folder structure looks as below:

[image: folder structure]

**Requirement & Challenge:** When I try to read the FixedTestFile.dat
from different features, the read method appends the path wrong followed by the path of feature file and hence fails.

Tried with the following ways to read the file but failed with error.

```
And multipart file myFile = { read: 'src/test/java/e2e/common/data/FixedTestFile.dat', filename: #(randomFileName), contentType: 'text/plain' }
```

**Logs:**
[image: Error]

**Requirement:** I have to read file "FixedTestFile.dat" from different features located in folders **individual** and **testScenarios** while using in Mutlipart file myFile.

Note : I tried with using classpath: and file: But no luck

```
And multipart file myFile = { read: 'classpath:e2e/common/data/FixedTestFile.dat', filename: #(randomFileName), contentType: 'text/plain' }
```

Tried using a variable for filename with path and tried using this as a parameter in read. Did not work.

```
* string myDataFileWithPath = "\'"+"../common/data/"+fileName+".dat"+"\'"
And multipart file myFile = { read: myDataFileWithPath, filename: #(randomFileName), contentType: 'text/plain' }
```

So the question is: **"How to read a file from two features in another location?"** Precisely for a multipart file upload.

Am I missing something or it is a bug while reading files?

Comment: I gave up trying to understand your question. follow this process if you can: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and see this, that's all I have to say: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: @PeterThomas, I tried editing the question adding the screenshots of error. I can submit it as an issue if it is still not understandable challenge.  Please dont come up with an answer saying if you can not find the answer, assume Karate is not a candidate for you.  We did 95% of work already and we can not come back.

Comment: there are others here who may have more patience than me. all the best. search the other answers on stack-overflow, I think that's the best option. and read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#reading-files